# Team Services build definition missing dacpacs in published artifacts

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-pipelines

I am trying to setup CI/CD in Visual Studio Team Services for my solution that contains an MVC project and a SQL Server Database project.

Using the ASP.NET (PREVIEW) template both projects in my solution get built but I am finding that the dacpac from my SQL Server Database project is not being published as an artifact and is not in the `C:\agent\_work\11\a` folder.

Do I need to create two build definitions one for each project in my solution? If so how should the parameter `Path to solution or packages.config` be configured.

Alternatively do I just need to add a `Copy Files` task to my build definition to transfer the dacpacs into the `C:\agent\_work\11\a` folder?

Comment: Do you solve this issue with our solutions?

Answer (score 2):

In general, I provide an MSBuild argument of `/p:OutDir=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` to the MSBuild or Visual Studio Build step. This forces all output to be put in the artifact staging folder.

If you do that and your DACPAC files **still** aren't in the artifact staging folder, then you may be building the wrong thing, or building a solution configuration/platform that has your SSDT projects set to not build.

Comment: This is the default MSBuild argument `/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"` which products 5 files in the artifact. What is the difference between that and your suggestion of the `OutDir` property?

Comment: @mheptinstall This argument is used to publish web project, it won't publish database project, so you need to add Copy Files task to copy dacpacs file to artifact folder.

Comment: Daniel Mann's answer worked for me. Only adding /p:OutDir=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) to the Visual Studio build task results in the DACPAC files being published to the drop folder.

Answer (score 0):

There are web and database project in a solution, you need to copy database project output to artifact folder with an extra task. (e.g. Copy Files task)

The argument: `/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"` is used to publish web project, it won’t publish database project.

Comment: Providing an additional `/p:OutDir=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` argument as I suggested should accomplish the same thing without the need for an extra Copy File task. I do this on a fairly regular basis.

Comment: @DanielMann Yes, but web project also output to the artifact folder, these files should be packaged in the zip file.